# Unity performance spikes at 30 FPS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, optimization, frame-rate

I am developing a simple game for **iOS** using Unity engine. I am using `Application.targetFrameRate` to set the target fps for my game. When I set target fps to 60 or 45, the game runs perfectly on any iOS device, but if I set targetFrameRate to 30, the game runs with spikes and jitter. I don't know why this is happening (30 fps must be OK).

I attached the **Profiler** to my iPhone and saw that when running at 30 fps, some frames are rendering at 200 fps, others at 45-60 fps and this causing the awful performance spikes. But this is not happening when targetFrameRate is 45 or 60.

I really need my game to run at 30 fps to avoid heating and throttling. Someone please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing at the underlying issue here but setting `targetFrameRate` throttles the frame through logic on the CPU while setting `QualitySettings.vSyncCount` lets the GPU handle the throttling. 
My guess is, that setting `QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 2` should provide a smoother experience. You can also set this manually in your QualitySettings instead of by code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me! There are still some small spikes but it really looks several times smoother than it was before